# Avell W1513 touchpad not working: pin cannot be used as irq on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: kernel, touchpad, synaptics

I have an Avell W1513 notebook and the touchpad doesn't work. It doesn't show on xinput list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD Webcam: HD Webcam                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

It looks like the kernel doesn't support it, but there is an error message on boot that might be a clue for the problem:

```
Jun  7 09:17:34 shrek4 kernel: [    3.615709] cannonlake-pinctrl INT3450:00: pin 263 cannot be used as IRQ
Jun  7 09:17:34 shrek4 kernel: [    3.615715] genirq: Setting trigger mode 8 for irq 132 failed (intel_gpio_irq_type+0x0/0x130 [pinctrl_intel])
Jun  7 09:17:34 shrek4 kernel: [    3.615891] i2c_hid i2c-UNIW0001:00: i2c-UNIW0001:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
Jun  7 09:17:34 shrek4 kernel: [    3.619111] cannonlake-pinctrl INT3450:00: pin 263 cannot be used as IRQ
Jun  7 09:17:34 shrek4 kernel: [    3.619116] genirq: Setting trigger mode 8 for irq 132 failed (intel_gpio_irq_type+0x0/0x130 [pinctrl_intel])
Jun  7 09:17:34 shrek4 kernel: [    3.619189] i2c_hid i2c-UNIW0001:00: Could not register for UNIW0001:00 interrupt, irq = 132, ret = -1
Jun  7 09:17:34 shrek4 kernel: [    3.619312] i2c_hid: probe of i2c-UNIW0001:00 failed with error -1
```

Not sure if the device generating these messages is the touchpad itself, but in [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2387719) the same message is happening on a similar touchpad problem.

Have already tried booting with acpi on, i8402 support kernel 4.17 and  `synaptics_i2c` module (plus blacklisting `i2c_hid`) without success.

As it's not a common brand the specs follow:

```
H/W path       Device     Class          Description
====================================================
                          system         1513 I7
/0                        bus            GI5CN5E
/0/0                      memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/3a                     memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/3a/0                   memory         [empty]
/0/3a/1                   memory         [empty]
/0/3a/2                   memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz 
/0/3a/3                   memory         [empty]
/0/45                     memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/46                     memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/47                     memory         9MiB L3 cache
/0/48                     processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GH
/0/100                    bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1                  bridge         Skylake PCIe Controller (x16)
/0/100/1/0                display        GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
/0/100/2                  display        Intel Corporation
/0/100/8                  generic        Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
/0/100/12                 generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/14                 bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/14/0    usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/4             multimedia     HD Webcam
/0/100/14/0/7             input          USB Receiver
/0/100/14/0/b             input          ITE Device(8291)
/0/100/14/0/e             communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/1    usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2               memory         RAM memory
/0/100/14.3    wlo1       network        Intel Corporation
/0/100/15                 bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/16                 communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/17                 storage        Intel Corporation
/0/100/1b                 bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1b.4               bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1d                 bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1d/0               generic        RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1d/0.1  enp4s0f1   network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit E
/0/100/1e                 communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f                 bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.3               multimedia     Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.4               bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.5               bus            Intel Corporation
/0/1           scsi1      storage        
/0/1/0.0.0     /dev/sda   disk           250GB WDC WDS250G2B0B-
/0/1/0.0.0/1              volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2   /dev/sda2  volume         232GiB EXT4 volume
/1                        power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```

The only alternative is to wait for the kernel to support it; or can anyone here think of a fixable problem (instead of a lack of support)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 19.04 the touchpad works like a charm - if you have the same problem it is worth updating.

Answer (score 0):

Avell vendors told me that they don't use Clevo parts. Howwever, I've found some notebooks from TongFang (a ODM manufacturer) that might be the ones that sell parts to Avell. At least, their cases and specifications look the same.

having said that, you might try to find Linux-related information by searching for similar items. the one that I've found is this:

http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/tongfang-gj5cn6e.816637/

Look at the Youtube review (just like Avell does from some company, they buy from Tongfang and resell wth their branding). It looks just like Avell notebooks.

The model in question is TongFang GJ5CN6E, but they have many others and maybe yours is one of those.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue on ASUS GL703GE:

canonlake-pinctrl INT3450:00:0 pin 225 cannot be used as IRQ

On Askubuntu:
[18.04 ITE 8910 touchpad on Asus Strix GL703GE not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038602/18-04-ite-8910-touchpad-on-asus-strix-gl703ge-not-working/1054427#1054427)

on Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1782653

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/pinctrl/intel/pinctrl-cannonlake.c#L328