# asus fx-503 touchpad and fn keys not working

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, touchpad, asus, brightness

After installing Ubuntu 18.04, the touchpad of my [Asus FX-503](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/FX503/specifications/) ([manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/GamingNB/FX503/0408_GK13137_FX503VD_VM_A.pdf)) has really low performance which is very vexing. Also, Function keys do not work for changing brightness or the keyboard back light.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910)           id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:3090 Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910)           id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Uname provides:
Linux sorush-FX503VD 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

How may I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Unfortunately, Asus does not provide Linux drivers for its hardware, as found at https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/FX503/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: so what should i do ? i know some people who have asus but they don`t have problem

Comment: 1) This could be an issue specific to this model, not an Asus-wide issue. 2) Look for other Ubuntu and Linux issues with the ELAN1200:00 04F3:3090 Touchpad  / ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910)   like https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038602/18-04-ite-8910-touchpad-on-asus-strix-gl703ge-not-working which was the first hit on a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after rading latest comment and upgrading ubuntu to 19.04 , and reaching kernel 5.0
function keys problem solved.
touchpad works better now . but some times stops suddenly and still has not expected performance , but at least its usable .