# fx503 touchpad freeze on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: touchpad, 19.04, freeze

after updating ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04 touch pad suddenly freezes for some seconds and it starts working again automatically .it repeats again and again .

Linux sorush-FX503VD 5.0.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 12 13:05:32 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
The problem with old ubuntu kernel was low performance, but here problem is freezing .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asus fx-503 touchpad and fn keys not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175997/asus-fx-503-touchpad-and-fn-keys-not-working)

Comment: i said the version of ubuntu is diffrent and problemis freezing not low performance

Comment: any one has any idea i think its Xorg that kills my touchpad .